# How to set JMeter Vars from within WebDriver Sampler?

Tags: javascript, webdriver, automated-tests, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

```
// I had previously used a CSS/JQuery extractor to get a URL from a page and add it to JMeter vars - accessing it here
var pageURL = "${valueFromJmeterVars}";

// navigate to that url
WDS.browser.get(pageURL); 

// selecting an element
var button = wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.cssSelector(buttonLocator)));                                                                                                                                               

// log desired boolean value to console, so I can confirm is as expected
WDS.log.info('reserveASpotButton:' + reserveASpotButton.isEnabled());

// add my boolean to JMeter vars, so I can access later from beanshell post-processor (where I do my assertions)
vars.put("reserveASpotButtonIsEnabled", reserveASpotButton.isEnabled());
```

The last line above doesn't work.

I can successfully use CSS/JQuery Extractor to add values to JMeter vars...

But how can I do the same from within WebDriver Sampler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access JMeter API classes from within the WebDriver Sampler, it's implemented as [JSR 223 standard](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=223) for instance you can refer JMeter Variables (aka `vars` as follows)

In the WebDriver Sampler:

```
var ctx = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext()
var vars = ctx.getVariables();

vars.put('foo','bar')
```

Now you have `${foo}` variable with the value of `bar`

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](http://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for more WDS sampler tips and tricks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to cast it to String first, as per [Using Selenium with JMeter's WebDriver Sampler guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) JMeter Variables are basically Strings and you can't put boolean there.

just replace

```
vars.put("reserveASpotButtonIsEnabled", reserveASpotButton.isEnabled());
```

with

```
vars.put("reserveASpotButtonIsEnabled", reserveASpotButton.isEnabled().toString());
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because 'vars' in not defined in WebDriver Sampler as in for instance BeanShell Sampler.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a clean way to do this, but it is possible.  You can set the response headers in your WebDriver sampler:

```
WDS.sampleResult.setResponseHeaders(reserveASpotButton.isEnabled())
```

Then you can use a [regular expression extractor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) to pull the data from the response headers.