# How to use JMeter Property props.get props.put from WebDriver Sampler (JMeter)

Tags: jmeter

I create some features/functions from first Thread Group and put them into a JMeter Property:

```
props.put("FUNCTIONS", new function());
```

Then I would like to call those features/functions in WebDriver Sampler of the other Thread Groups.

In normal way (BSF, Beanshell or JSR223), just using:

```
props.get("FUNCTIONS")
```

But how to do this in WebDriver Sampler?

There is the same question related to `vars` here :

- [How to pass variable in Webdriver-Sampler | Jmeter Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181304/how-to-pass-variable-in-webdriver-sampler-jmeter-webdriver)
- [How to set JMeter Vars from within WebDriver Sampler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817398/how-to-set-jmeter-vars-from-within-webdriver-sampler)

Could anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little bit weird to hear such a question from someone who is familiar with Beanshell, however here you go:

Something like:

```
var props = org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.getJMeterProperties()
```

will provide you read/write access to JMeter Properties.

References:

- [JMeterUtils.getJMeterProperties()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html#getJMeterProperties())
- [Using Java From Scripts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)

Comment: How can I say thank you to you @Dmitri T, I read many your article from www.blazemeter.com.
This question, I tried many APIs before, even I tried [JMeterUtils](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html): 
but I used getProperty() instead of getJMeterProperties() as your comment, that's why I have to ask a question here.
Again. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, could you please spend a little bit time to answer my question [here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter). This is also your article related to JMeter...