# How to use WDS variable in BSF or JSR233 (JMeter)

Tags: webdriver, jmeter

I experienced the issue with Webdriver Sampler in JMeter. I would like to define some functions in JSR233, then call them from the other Thread Groups. But I don't know how to use WDS as Webdriver Sampler.

The Test Plan looks like:

- Test Plan

  - setUp Thread Group

    - JSR233 Sampler (define function)
  - Thread Group 1

    - Webdriver Sampler A (call function from JSR233)
    - Webdriver Sampler B

And the function which I defined, like this:

```
var WDS = com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverScriptable;
var getBroswer = WDS.browser.get('http://www.google.com.vn');
```

but I got the error

```
2016/07/06 16:19:06 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BSFSampler: BSF error org.apache.bsf.BSFException: JavaScript Error: Java class "com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverScriptable" has no public instance field or method named "browser".
at org.apache.jmeter.util.BSFJavaScriptEngine.handleError(BSFJavaScriptEngine.java:202)
at org.apache.jmeter.util.BSFJavaScriptEngine.eval(BSFJavaScriptEngine.java:152)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BSFSampler.sample(BSFSampler.java:98)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:465)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:410)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:241)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So, my question is, how to use `WDS`, also `WDS.browser` when I define function in BSF,JSR233?

I think the way to do is the same these questions:

- [How to use JMeter Property props.get props.put from WebDriver Sampler (JMeter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184430/how-to-use-jmeter-property-props-get-props-put-from-webdriver-sampler-jmeter/38187454#38187454)
- [How to pass variable in Webdriver-Sampler | Jmeter Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181304/how-to-pass-variable-in-webdriver-sampler-jmeter-webdriver)
- [How to set JMeter Vars from within WebDriver Sampler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817398/how-to-set-jmeter-vars-from-within-webdriver-sampler)

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably `WDS.getBrowser().get...`

Comment: The same problem :( thanks for your suggest, I will try another way...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to share BSF functions across different Thread Groups, consider using [Beanshell Test Elements](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) and [bsh.shared namespace](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) instead.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri

First, after definition the function in BSF, I will store it into the property by `props`.

Second, using Beanshell, it's pure Java, how can I use it in WebDriver Sampler (using javascript)?

Third, even using bsh.shared namespace, I need to define the function first, and inside my function, it must contains some code like `WDS.browser...`. So how can I use `WDS` or `WDS.browser` to define my functions, then I can call them from Webdriver Sampler?